# Which Computer Vision / Image Processing technique would solve light imbalance in images?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, image-manipulation, image-processing, computer-vision

Given a colour image whose light intensity is dim at the edges and bright in the middle, such as **[dim    bright    dim]**, which computer vision technique would be recommended to correct this imbalance?

While I believe [Histogram Equalisation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html) could help, I've read that it also introduces an unrealistic look to an image by exaggerating the blue channel.

I consider implementing an image processor for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One classic approach is using top hat filtering for leveling uneven illumination. You should perform morphological opening with a large structuring element, then remove the result from the original image.

If you have dark objects on light background you should do bottom hat filtering (dual of top hat filtering): subtract the closing with a large structuring element from the original image.

[image: Result of top hat filtering]

Comment: Thanks WebMonster. I'll take a look at this as I've never heard the name before. Does this approach work equally as well with coloured images as it does greyscale?

Comment: I don't know if there is a generalization of morphological operators for colored images. You could convert the image to HSV color space, process the V channel as a grayscale image, then display the image. There will be some colour bleeding, but it could be good enough depending on your goals.